# Boruta Features Selection in R

Tags: r

I am performing Fraud Detection in R and I have done one hot encoding on all categorical variables and the resulting transformed data will have 1500 variables. Now on performing features selection using the Boruta algorithm, the object will be so big that R can not handle at 7.8 GB and it will obvious be costly to run as it will take a lot of time. How best can I do my features selection?